# Did a war memorial in Australia have a Japanese flag on the floor to trample?

Tags: japan, world-war-ii, australia

From twitter:

> Australia's 'HATE' against JPN; War memorial hall in Sydney require
>   visiters to trample down JP flag./ @mizubasyo シドニ

[image: Example photo in question]

"シドニ" is Japanese for "Sydney".

Is this photo from a war memorial in Australia?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This was noted by [Masamune Wada](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Masamune_Wada), a Japanese politician belonging to the centre-right [Your Party](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Your_Party). A tweet about the photo, and mentioning Masamune Wada, can be seen [here](https://twitter.com/mizubasyo/status/387578066169364480) The [Japanese language Wikipedia article](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%92%8C%E7%94%B0%E6%94%BF%E5%AE%97) about him, translated via Google Translate, says

> September 2013, the Australian War Memorial visit time, World War II
>   on the floor of the corner of the Rising Sun flag and discovered that
>   video is being projected, the museum and the Australian government
>   protests `[6] [5]` . After that, the Australian government in response
>   to the proposal from Current Australian Embassy of Japan, withdrew a
>   projection of the video until October 15 `[8]`.

Even without relying upon Wikipedia, it's possible to conclude the image is genuine.

Doing a google search for the image gave pages such as http://2ch.ki9.biz/archives/18383.html, which also had the following image:

[image: another image, with surroundings as well]

In this image, the flag (the [Rising Sun Flag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rising_Sun_Flag), not the ordinary [Flag of Japan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_Japan)) can be seen on the floor. However, it is part of a exhibition about World War II, and in this instance it can be walked around if one so wishes. (That being said, I'm rather surprised that a war memorial let a flag be projected upon the floor - I thought they would treat flags, even enemy ones, more sensitively than that)

That image can be seen at [A sombre experience at the Australian War Memorial, Canberra](http://www.theroadtoanywhere.com/a-sombre-experience-at-the-australian-war-memorial-canberra/), (not Sydney) a blog post by Dean Wickham showing several photos from the memorial.

Comment: Similarly, [Canadian War Museum turns off 'insulting' flag exhibits](http://www.cbc.ca/news/canada/ottawa/canadian-war-museum-turns-off-insulting-flag-exhibits-1.649486)

Comment: I suspect they simply thought it was an interesting design element and never considered the "trampling" aspect.  For contrast, [here](http://news.yahoo.com/photos/american-flag-projected-onto-ice-during-national-anthem-photo-050326567.html) is a picture of a US flag being "trampled", by people with sharp metal blades on their feet no less, as thousands cheer: and it seems clear from context that no disrepect is intended :-)

Comment: In fact, it is impossible to trample this flag - because it's projected from above, the moment you try to step on it, *it* ends up on top of *you*.